# Salesforce Classic / Inline VisualForce Page - Can an inline VF page be edited while editing the main record (at the same time)?

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce, action, edit, salesforce-classic

Pretty simple question I think - but I googled it and searched for it on Salesforce stack to no avail so far.

I have an inline VisualForce page (using the standard controller obviously) that sits inline in the middle of one of my Opportunity page layouts and dynamically renders specific fields depending on the type of Opportunity. They are all Opportunity fields, no cross object fields. However, when the user presses the standard Edit button on the record to modify the data, the inline Visualforce section doesn't appear on the standard edit page.

I know I can enable inline editing on the VF page, or add separate command buttons for edit/save, but is there any way for me to allow my users to edit the standard record data AND the inline VisualForce field data at the same time from the same screen?

Comment: Nope. Not possible.

Comment: Yeeah that's what I thought, I just wanted to exhaust all options before I gave up. I guess the only way to do it would be to override the edit page with a custom edit page that handles the same dynamic rendering. Thanks for the prompt response! @AdrianLarson

Comment: Well... maybe...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggested line of pursuit. No guarantees and I haven't tried it myself. I may later if I have time.

Try adding an `onunload` event listener to your inline page that saves the edits made from that page. You may need to use a `@future` method to avoid row locking issues. You can pass an entire object as a `String` using `JSON` serialization. You can lock the row in this method by re-querying for the record using a `FOR UPDATE` clause.

Who knows, it might even work.

Comment: and if this does work, whoever does this should document carefully in the VF markup how and why it works as the coordination won't be obvious to the next dev/admin inheriting the implementation

Comment: Fair point. Hence why my knee-jerk reaction was that it's not possible. Probably somewhat unwise to implement this strategy, but it would be interesting to play with. Maybe you could add a `window.confirm` to verify the user wants to save the edits.